# MailChimp MCAPI.NET - Subscription Groupings

Tags: c#, .net, mailchimp, mcapi.net

I'm interfacing with MailChimp using MCAPI.NET and I need to specify the groupings for subscriptions.

```
        string emailAddr = "somebody@somewhere.net";
        MailChimp.MCApi mc = new MailChimp.MCApi("myapikey", true);

        var merges = new MailChimp.Types.List.Merges();
        merges.Add("FNAME", "MyFirstName");
        merges.Add("LNAME", "MyLastName");

        var group = new string[]{"PSS"};
        var grp = new MailChimp.Types.List.Grouping("Staff Type", group);
        merges.Add("Groupings", grp);

        mc.ListSubscribe("mylistid", emailAddr, merges);
```

My grouping isn't getting set. Does someone have a working example they could share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are not adding a list of groupings to the merge var "Groupings". The value has to be of the following type:

```
MailChimp.Types.MCList<MailChimp.Types.List.Grouping>
```

Here is a working copy:

```
var merges = new List.Merges();
var groupingList = new MailChimp.Types.MCList<MailChimp.Types.List.Grouping>();
var grouping = new MailChimp.Types.List.Grouping(myGroupId, new string[] { group1, group2 });
groupingList.Add(grouping);

merges["Groupings"] = groupingList;

// You may find it practical to include the following options, at least while testing the groupings
var options = new MailChimp.Types.List.SubscribeOptions();
options.DoubleOptIn = false;
options.ReplaceInterests = false;
options.SendWelcome = false;

mcapi.ListSubscribe(myMailChimpListId, email, merges, options);
```